# Representing a Fan Shaped Image on a Map using Python

Tags: python, gis

I am looking to display an object (fan shaped object with each protruding line at the 'ID Angle' from the vertical) on a map using the below table as input:

Table (input):
[image]

Fan shaped object:

[image]

I am able to display a point on a map using python (very easy). My problem so far has been with coming up with a way to represent each protruding line as per the above object.

I would appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**

Please see below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

longitude = [4.3323, 4.3323, 4.3323]
latitude = [2.3433, 2.3433, 2.3433]
x,y = map(longitude, latitude)
map.plot(x, y, 'bo', markersize=18)
plt.show()
```

So basically i have been able to represent these data points with a point.

I need to integrate the directional improvements as I earlier stated.

Comment: Still I don't understand the question. It seems you are not using longitude and latitude values from the input data, while the angles have something to do with the plot. If we fix the code, you got different input values which shows three point on the surface. I don't understand how you got these points and how do you want to find the centre mathematically?

Comment: I posted wrong input values. Sorry I was referencing another project. Anyway, it is the same set of codes. I have modified them to show one location on the map. Could you kindly advise on fixing the code to show the fan-like objects. Thanks.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong:
you have a centre point on the surface let's say (4.3323, 2.3433) then you have 3 wings of this "fan" with defined angles from 12 o'clock: (60, 120, 240) which are (Ace_1, Ace_2, Ace_3) but there is no definite length for these wings. Right?

Comment: Correct. There is not definite length.

Comment: Thank you Mehdi. You have been very helpful. It works just fine, exactly what I needed.

Comment: you can accept the answer if it was satisfactory :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

center = (4.3323, 2.3433)
angles = [60, 120, 240]
angles = [a/180.0*np.pi for a in angles]

# scale
l = 1

# the center point
x, y = center

# draw each line
for a in angles:
    dx = l * np.sin(a)
    dy = l * np.cos(a)
    plt.plot([x, x + dx], [y, y + dy], 'k-')

# draw the center circle
plt.plot(x, y, 'wo', ms=l*100)
plt.show()
```